# INSTALLING ASSAULT CUBE, how to

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded Assault cube from the website, and now I dont know how to install it. I'm new to ubuntu. please help. I have the .tar.biz file and extracted it to downloads. I doubled clicked install.sh and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands on terminal,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/install.sh
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```